# Implied Risk Neutral Probability Density from Iron Butterfly

Tags: options

It's known that we can get the implied RND from a butterfly as (DF is discount factor)

```
P(S(T) = K) = DF * [C(K + X)+ c(K - X) - 2C(K)]/X^2
```

But how to get the same density from 4 strikes : `K(ATM PUT) , K(OTM PUT) , K(ATM CALL) , K(OTM CALL)`(i.e Iron Butterfly). The 4 strikes are chosen such that the net delta of the structure is zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Background

If I understand you correctly, you want to know how to approximate a second derivative to a function i.e. $\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x^2}$, using a generalized finite difference approximation with unequal step sizes.

This task is usually approached by solving a linear equation system based on Taylor series expansions of the function $f$ around some point $x_0$, here up to the second order:

$$
\begin{align}
f(x_0+a)&\approx f(x_0)+af'(x_0)+\frac{1}{2}a^2f''(x_0)\\
f(x_0)&=f(x_0)\\
f(x_0-b)&\approx f(x_0)-bf'(x_0)+\frac{1}{2}b^2f''(x_0)\\
\\
\Rightarrow \begin{pmatrix}f(x_0+a)\\f(x_0)\\f(x_0-b)\end{pmatrix}&=\begin{pmatrix}1&a&\frac{1}{2}a^2\\
1&0&0\\
1&-b&\frac{1}{2}b^2\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}f(x_0)\\f'(x_0)\\f''(x_0)\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
$$
This 3x3 linear equation system is solved via ([I used some online matrix inversion tool)](https://www.symbolab.com/solver/matrix-inverse-calculator/inverse%20%5Cbegin%7Bpmatrix%7D1%20%26%20a%26%200.5%5Ccdot%20a%5E%7B2%7D%20%5C%5C%201%20%26%200%20%26%200%20%5C%5C%201%20%26%20-b%20%26%200.5%5Ccdot%20b%5E%7B2%7D%5Cend%7Bpmatrix%7D?or=input):

$$
\begin{align}
\begin{pmatrix}f(x_0)\\f'(x_0)\\f''(x_0)\end{pmatrix}&=\begin{pmatrix}1&a&\frac{1}{2}a^2\\
1&0&0\\
1&-b&\frac{1}{2}b^2\end{pmatrix}^{-1}\begin{pmatrix}f(x_0+a)\\f(x_0)\\f(x_0-b)\end{pmatrix}\\
&=\begin{pmatrix}0&1&0\\
\frac{b}{a(a+b)}&\frac{1}{b}-\frac{1}{a}&-\frac{a}{b(a+b)}\\
\frac{2}{a(a+b)}&-\frac{2}{ab}&\frac{2}{b(a+b)}
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}f(x_0+a)\\f(x_0)\\f(x_0-b)\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
$$

And we find the generalized approximation as:

$$
f''(x_0)\approx \frac{2}{a(a+b)}f(x_0+a)-\frac{2}{ab}f(x_0)+\frac{2}{b(a+b)}f(x_0-b)
$$

Note that if $a=b=h$, the *usual* approximation formula results, i.e.

$$
f''(x_0)=\frac{1}{h^2}\left(f(x_0+a)-2f(x_0)+f(x_0-b)\right)
$$

---

### Application

The first step would be to transform the OTM PUT option price into an ITM CALL option price using put call parity. Then we'd have all required ingredients for our equation system, i.e. $K_{ITM}, C(K_{ITM})$, $K_{ATM}, C(K_{ATM})$ and $K_{OTM}, C(K_{OTM})$.

$$
\begin{align}
C(K_{OTM})&\approx C(K_{ATM})+C'(K_{ATM})(K_{OTM}-K_{ATM})+\frac{1}{2}C''(K_{ATM})(K_{OTM}-K_{ATM})^2\\
C(K_{ATM})&= C(K_{ATM})\\
C(K_{ITM})&\approx C(K_{ATM})-C'(K_{ATM})(K_{ITM}-K_{ATM})+\frac{1}{2}C''(K_{ATM})(K_{ITM}-K_{ATM})^2
\end{align}
$$

and we can now reuse the solution from above with $a=K_{OTM}-K_{ATM}$ and $b=K_{ITM}-K_{ATM}$.